# python - buttons on top of tab frame but tab frame will not fill remaining area below

Tags: python, button, tabs, frame

Creating code to produce the buttons on top of tab frame but as you see I can get the tab frame to fill the remaining part of the window.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fw63j.png)

I've tried using grid and pack to position and fill but no luck.

Comment: Please [edit] to include a [mcve] of your code, and also please indicate and tag your question with the framework/library you are using.

Comment: figure it out. i used a LabelFrame and put all my buttons in the LabelFrame and position on top of tab frame and positioned using pack which still allowed me to use grid inside of labelframe and tabframe.